# uninitialized constant HTTPSuccess (NameError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

I am trying to learn some ruby http request response code from this tutorial -

http://danknox.github.io/2013/01/27/using-rubys-native-nethttp-library/

Code so far -

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://api.random.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

# Continuing our example from above

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/search?question=somequestion")
response = http.request(request)

# response.code
# response.body

case response
when HTTPSuccess
  response.body
when HTTPRedirect
  follow_redirect(response) # you would need to implement this method
else
  raise StandardError, "Something went wrong :("
end
```

error -

```
Test.rb:16: uninitialized constant HTTPSuccess (NameError)
```

I saw the only stack overflow post on this issue. Did not help. Why could this be happening ?

Comment: Per this documentation (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPSuccess.html), maybe you need to prefix it with Net:: (e.g., `when Net::HTTPSuccess`)?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure - Correct. I'll have to use namespace. How to do it without namespace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `HTTPSuccess` has not been initialized. Try using `Net::HTTPSuccess` (and `Net::HTTPRedirection`) instead.

Also, change your case statement to `case response.class`.  In your when statements you're checking for class equality.

Comment: Now, I get this error - `24: uninitialized constant Net::HTTPRedirect (NameError)`.